# QuantLib 1.9 install on OS X

Tags: macos, boost, installation, quantlib

The error clang: `error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

on running the compile example, from http://quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml,

```
g++ -I/opt/local/include/ -I/opt/local/include/boost BermudanSwaption.cpp \
    -o bermudanswaption -L/opt/local/lib/ -lQuantLib
```

Error message is:

```
clang -cc1 version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1) default target x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/local/include
 /opt/local/include/boost
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.12.0 -o bermudanswaption -L/opt/local/lib/ /var/folders/m3/39_h4bg52xzfv8800_zrkvrh0000gn/T/BermudanSwaption-a73fac.o -lQuantLib -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/8.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
......
  "QuantLib::detail::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, QuantLib::detail::percent_holder const&)", referenced from:
      calibrateModel(boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::ShortRateModel> const&, std::__1::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::CalibrationHelper>, std::__1::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::CalibrationHelper> > > const&) in BermudanSwaption-a73fac.o
      _main in BermudanSwaption-a73fac.o
  "QuantLib::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, QuantLib::Date const&)", referenced from:
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::valueDate(QuantLib::Date const&) const in BermudanSwaption-a73fac.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`

What does this mean and why is LLVM invoked? I'm using latest Xcode, Mac OSX 10.12.1, familiar with python but not command line installs or compilation....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very simple. You only compiled **BermudanSwaption.cpp** but you also need to compile the entire QuantLib. Otherwise, the linker can't find the implementation.

Comment: Thank you. Which part of error describes this? @Student T